# how to close the burger menu after selection? javascript

Tags: jquery, css, menu, frontend

Last year I followed a website design course.
The lady is explained step by step all in detail, but one thing is not clear to me. when an item from the hamburger menu is selected in the mobile version, it remains open.

this is my site so you can try it!

[my site](https://hydrographic-suisse.ch/)

this is the piece of code that is in charge of opening the menu:

```js
$('.js--nav-icon').click(function() {
  var nav = $('.js--main-nav');
  var icon = $('.js--nav-icon ion-icon');
  nav.slideToggle(200);
  icon.attr('name', icon.attr('name') === 'menu-outline' ? 'close-outline' : 'menu-outline');
});
```

Comment: can any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you need to bind a new event handler to the `a` elements within the burger menu. This event handler will find the `.js--nav-icon` and close it by calling `slideToggle()` again:

```js
var $nav = $('.js--main-nav');
var $iconContainer = $('.js--nav-icon');

let changeBurgerNameAttr = $c => $c.find('ion-icon').attr('name', (i, name) => name === 'menu-outline' ? 'close-outline' : 'menu-outline');

// toggle burger on click
$iconContainer.on('click', e => {
  $nav.slideToggle(200);
  changeBurgerNameAttr($iconContainer);
});

// hide burger when item selected
$nav.on('click', 'a', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  $nav.slideUp(200);
  changeBurgerNameAttr($iconContainer);
});
```

Comment: we got it to close the menu, but there is an error when the button is pressed before opening, it opens and closes itself 5 times ..

Comment: That behaviour sounds like you're binding the event multiple times. It's hard to debug without seeing the actual code, so if you require further help could you please edit the question to include a working example in the snippet, not a link to your website.